# Angular-ui-router different templates based on params

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have one state in my ui-router config:

```
state("objects",
  url: "/:type/"
)
```

And I need render different templates based on `:type` params. For example, when user trying access `/buy`, I need render template `/views/objects/buy.html`, when `/rent` — `/views/objects/rent.html`.

What can help me?

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood you correctly. For example, if you have base url objects
Your state will be:

```js
.state('objects.rent') {
    url: "/rent",
    data: '{name: 'rent'},
    views: {
        // for one or multiple views
       'rentView': {templateUrl: '/views/objects/rent.html'}
    } 
}

// If you need to get something or initialize:
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',
      function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
         if ($rootScope.$state.current.data !== undefined && $rootScope.$state.current.data.name !== undefined && $rootScope.$state.current.data.name === 'rent') {
           // doSomething
         } 
    });
```